# Auto Value for setBounds

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

How can I achive an automatic value with setBounds example:

```
myJPanel.setBounds(0, 0, [auto], 300);
```

I am using box layout and want the width automatically calculated like it would be when I don't call setBounds. I hope this makes sense to you, thanks in advance!

Comment: The width is automatically calculated when you use a layout manager. There is no need to use the setBounds() method. If the BoxLayout is not working the way you expect it to work, the post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: The width is, but not the height.

Comment: Yes, the height is determined when you use a BoxLayout. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is automatically set when you don't call setBounds, why not grab the width then?

```
int w =myJpanel.getWidth();
myJPanel.setBounds(0, 0, w, 300);
```

Comment: You should NOT be using setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size of the panel.